# How to show the text from a form with button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text

I am studying web design for first year in university. We have just started and I am trying to do different things with my basic knowledge of html. My question is how can it show the text entered in a form after clicking a button? I tried something but it's not working.

This is my wrong code:

```
 <body>
    <script> 
        function name(name1)
        { alert ("Your name is" + name1)
        }
    </script>

    Enter a name:
    <form> <input type="text" name="name1"/></form> </br>

    <button onclick="name(name1)">Click!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: declaring function you name arguments whatever, when using function need to pass in data, `name1` is undefined at point you are trying to pas in to function as data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<body>
    <script> 
        function name1(name)
        { 
        alert("Your name is " + name);
        }       
    </script>

    Enter a name:
    <form> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></form> </br>
    <button onclick="name1(document.getElementById('name').value)">Click!</button>    

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can to use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), to get the element based using [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```html
<script>
  function yourMethod(name1) {
    var inputName = document.querySelector('input[name=' + name1 + ']').value;
    console.log("Your name is: " + inputName)
  }
</script>

Enter a name:
<input type="text" name="name1" />
<button onclick="yourMethod('name1')">Click!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

make `onclick="name()"`

then `function name(){ alert( document.querySelector("input[name='name1']").value )  }`

what it does is when the button gets clicked, the function name is called. This will alert the text by finding the element with the querySelector. The query selector returns an element, if found. You can access every elements attribute with element.attributeName.

In this case you want to use querySelecor because querySelectorAll will return a nodelist. Where querySelector will return only an element

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<body>
<script> 
    function name()
    {
       var value = document.getElementById('name1').value;
       alert("Your name is" + value);
    }
</script>

Enter a name:
<form>
   <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" />
</form>
</br>
<button onclick="name();">Click!</button>
</body>
```